# Printing form with pictures

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, printing

I'm trying to print out a form that a customer has filled out for them to sign, and then store in our folders, but I can't figure out how to print forms properly. I've tried tons of guides or tutorials online, but I was only able to take a picture of the form and print that, which looked awful.

Is there any way I can print my form, which contains controls, labels, and pictures, in professional quality? I've heard about plugins for visual studio that might be able to do this, and if its not too much of a hassle, price might not be too much of a factor.

If it matters, all my controls are contained in form2, and the printing will be done from a menustrip-button in form2 aswell.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PrintDocument](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx&ei=SWpXUrrXLoKOyAH8qICoAg&usg=AFQjCNGSvVV-3sGogJZCkcZLc2FSz10xgg&sig2=cSt1s-kip54aXVGEWPoqeQ&bvm=bv.53899372,d.aWc) would be the way to go. It uses `GDI+` for drawing to the surface of the document. Your now in charge of the layout.

```
 private void pd_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PrintPageEventArgs)
   {
   single yPos = 0;
   int count = 0;
   single leftMargin = e.MarginBounds.Left;
   single topMargin = e.MarginBounds.Top;
   Image img = Image.FromFile({path to img});
   Rectangle logo = New Rectangle(40,40,50,50);
   using (Font printFont = new Font("Arial", 10.0f))
    { 
     e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, logo);
     e.Graphics.DrawString(textbox1.Text, printFont, Brushes.Black, leftMargin, yPos, New StringFormat());
    }
   //etc...
   //taken from the example and added how to draw the text from a textbox
   }
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I go about adding, lets say, a simple textbox to my document to be printed? I don't see any examples of adding controls in the link provivided

Comment: @user2856410 You cannot "add" a text box. You can draw text on a surface at an arbitrary position.

Comment: Am I able to add an image too?

Comment: Updated with example.

Comment: Examples in the wrong language :p I should be able to work it out, thanks